# Is it possible to update widget using remote notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm trying to create the app that updates the widget when the server sends a push notification.
But I'm not sure if this is possible.
Has anyone developed the app related to this?
If that's not possible, I'll try to figure out another way not using push notification.

Comment: It seems to me like a notification extension may be able to trigger the refresh method on WidgetKit. Have you tried something like that? Or what else did you try?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. I just found this page (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754880/how-to-reload-timeline-of-ios-14-widget-from-notification-response). According to Jordan H, it seems possible, but not real-time update. I'll test about that and post the results!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trigger the remote notification using the **userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)** and **application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)** methods of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.

What exactly I wanted was to change the widget in real time when a silent push came.

However, according to [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app)...

Because silent push has limitations (1. number per hour limit, 2. Possibility not to be delivered), it was difficult to update the widget in real time.

So my conclusion is,

It is possible to update the widget using remote notification, but it is difficult to use it in a way that updates the widget in real time in the background.

Comment: Couldn't you use a notification service extension with an entitlement that enables the notification to be surpressed from being displayed. Then the limitations  of silent notifications are eliminated

Answer (score 0):

The suitable solution is to start a `CLLocationManager` in the background.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background

After that, your app can run in the background to execute codes (without user terminates/kills it).
Then you can apply a Real-time event listener to refresh Widget info.

You can **reduce the accuracy and increase distanceFilter** to **reduce power consumption**. It is like you just keep app in background but don't need Device location data.

Comment: If I ever knew that an app on my iPhone is doing that, I will uninstall it, report it to Apple, and publish on my social networks informing all my friends and relatives to uninstall it. And that's of course after the dreaded one-start review on the App Store.